# Строительская / строительная поселковая школа

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, топонимика

**Школа в поселке Строитель?**  (Пример условный, хотя такой поселок есть.)
Предложили "строительная" — смешно получилось.
По логике надо бы "строительская" — но тут странно получается уже потому, что два обычно несочетаемых суффикса.

Comment: Почему несочетаемых? Я вот работаю на Учительской улице.

Comment: Люби**тельск**ая улица...

Comment: @Alex_ander  Учитель - это же не топоним. А к топонимам тут свой подход... Хотя, согласен, и это лыко в строку.  Но вот если бы хоть один пример, чтоб топоним с суффиксом -"ель" + "ский".

Comment: Лучший выход – "школа в поселке Строитель". Мы же не заморачиваемся поиском однословного наименования для жителей условных Малых Пяток?

Comment: Строителевская, строителинская. Варианты условные.

Comment: @Niemand мы заморачиваемся поиском лучшего выхода. Вопрос академический. Есть ли правильная форма - и если есть то какая. Остальное - в пользу бедных.

Comment: @shampar Условный вариант - это хорошо. ***Вот в поселке*** "***Труд***" ***будет*** "***трудовская***". Но вопрос не в поиске условного варианта, это пример был условный. А вариант хотелось бы академически обосновагнный.

Comment: @behemothus Коктеб**ель**_**ский** поселковый совет - есть такая статья в "википедии".

Comment: @Alex_ander  *Коктебельский поселковый совет* - с него все и началось ))) Не с совета, правда, но с Коктебеля. С ним все понятно, Но там нет суффикса, а значит и правила как такового. Поэтому  возник Строитель, где, увы, нет совета.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Академически* обосновать я, конечно, не смогу, но примеры построения и употребления топонимов с "ель" + "ский" есть ([строительный // строительский — паронимы](http://yaxy.ru/dictionaries/dic_par/19.html)).

**А**. 19. Ивано-Строительская начальная школа ([Школы Староюрьевского района, 1946 г.](http://nap-novik.narod.ru/skoli_1946.htm))

**Б.** В 1973 году (…) Спайковский совхозный поселковый совет переименован в Победительский с переносом центра из посёлка Спайка в посёлок Победитель.
 8. Победительское сельское поселение (село Победитель).
[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD)

**В.** МОУ Красно-Строительская средняя общеобразовательная школа
(446842, Самарская область, Челно-Вершинский район, с. Красный Строитель, ул. Школьная, 1А; место для голосования).